# Process Builder is the solution maybe ?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

So I'm having a requirement where I will be creating a checkbox in the Accounts object and each user has a maximum of 10 checks that they check for the checkbox for different Account records.

So I thought creating a counter at the User object level will work but I'm not able cross reference Account fields from the User object level.

What is the solution ? If it is Process Builder can someone help me how I can write a flow condition which should check for a count less than 10 and also increment the field whenever a check has been made by the user upto 10 checks.

Answer (score 2):

`Process Builder` is not capable of record validation, so no. A `Validation Rule` can enforce that at most 10 boxes are checked, but not by whom. The criteria would be something like:

```
10 <=
IF(Checkbox1__c, 1, 0) +
IF(Checkbox2__c, 1, 0) +
IF(Checkbox3__c, 1, 0) +
IF(Checkbox4__c, 1, 0) +
IF(Checkbox5__c, 1, 0)
```

`Process Builder` could help you track which boxes were checked by whom, but at that point I think you would probably need to use an `Apex Trigger` to count these values by user.

To determine how many `Account` records a `User` has checked this box for, you could create a lookup called, say, `Checked_By__c`, which I think you could update with `Workflow` whenever the box is checked with `{!$User.Id}`. You should also add a `Workflow` that clears the lookup if the box gets unchecked. From there, you can use Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Rollup Summaries for Lookups](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) tool in order to roll up this lookup to a new field on `User` called, say, `Boxes_Checked__c`. Once you have done the above, the `Validation Rule` is fairly straightforward: `Boxes_Checked__c > 10`. You might want the rule to be on `Account` though to be more clear (and add to the checkbox), so you would change that to `$User.Boxes_Checked__c > 10`.

More succinctly delineated steps:

1. Workflow Rule - Populate lookup when box is checked
2. Workflow Rule - Clear lookup when box is unchecked
3. DLRS - Roll up number of checked `Account` records
4. Validation on check box: `$User.Boxes_Checked__c > 10`